# 「スケジュール感をすり合わせましょう」 - what exactly are we going to discuss?

Tags: slang, business-japanese

When I first received an invitation to a meeting containing words similar to 「スケジュール感をすり合わせましょう」 I thought we are going to discuss the schedule so that "everyone is on the same page". The schedule would be presented so that everyone gets an understanding of it. Hence 感 "the feeling", like in 義務感 or 切迫感.

However after reading [スケジュール感って何？](http://oshiete.goo.ne.jp/qa/1653692.html) I am less convinced it was the case.

I understand スケジュール感 is a made-up word, but what exactly does 感 convey here? Would it be a discussion about an objective schedule (with possibilities to alter it according to the opinions) or everyone's subjective understanding of the given schedule?

If the latter - why 感? Are there other similar usages of 感?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my own words, the relatively new word  「スケジュール[感]{かん}」 is most often used to refer to:

> "one's rough ***image*** of when and how things should be conducted on a timeline (towards a goal)"

In other words, the "final" schedule does not exist on paper yet.

「スケジュール感をすり[合]{あ}わせましょう。」, therefore, would mean:

> "Let's compare and adjust our スケジュール感!"

Again, it is not saying "Let's make the final schedule!" even though that ***might*** happen if things went unexpectedly well at the meeting.

The 「感」 here would mean 「～～に[関]{かん}する[感覚]{かんかく}」 or 「～～の感じ」.

Comment: So how was this term coined from a linguistic point of view? If 感 was used by analogy to 義務感 or then スケジュール感 would be like "an attitude to keep up with schedule". If it was like 安心感, then "feelings towards the schedule". However here it seems more like 目的意識 to me. Something you can acquire and modify by a conscious effort. It could be that Japanese 感 has broader meaning than my definition of "feeling", hence my question about similar 〇〇感 usage.

Comment: 「およその/だいたいのスケジュール」って意味ですかね・・・? ググってて、「サイズ感」ってのが見つかったけど、「およその/おおまかなサイズ」みたいな感じじゃないかなぁ・・・(他にはそれらしいものは見つけられなかった・・)